# how to set listview's position after configuration change

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I'm struggling to recover my position in a listview on screen rotation configuration change.

Amongst the many things I've tried I came to this:

```
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
...
                mVisibleItem = -1;
            } else {
                if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(LV_VISIBLE_ITEM)) {
                    mVisibleItem = savedInstanceState.getInt(LV_VISIBLE_ITEM);
                }
            }
            setRetainInstance(true);
        }
```

and here I'm trying to set the position in the listview

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mVisibleItem > 0) {
        mlvDictionaryIndex.setSelectionFromTop(mVisibleItem, 0);
    }
}
```

However, much to my surprise, after rotating the screen and watching mVisibleItem  gets set with the correct value, in onResume I see that mVisibleItem  equals -1. How come?

Answer (score 1):

use `onSavedInstanceState` to write in the bundle the returned value of `ListView.onSaveInstanceState()`, and restored it onActivityCreated

```
 @Override
 public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (mListView != null) {
            outState.putParcelable(LISTVIEW_INTERNAL_STATE_KEY, mListView.onSaveInstanceState());
        }
 }
```

after the data are reload then you can call

```
mListView.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState.getParcelable(LISTVIEW_INTERNAL_STATE_KEY));
```

Answer (score 0):

Override onSaveInstanceState such as below"

```
    @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("pos", pos);
}
```

Then in your onCreate method have read the savedInstanceState to check if this is an orientation change or a new activity.

```
private int pos = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
     //This is a new activity
    }else{
      pos = savedInstanceState.getInt("");
    }
```

Now you have the position in the list, and you can scroll to this in configuration change.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe after the data in the `listview` is reloaded，the code below will work.

```
 mlvDictionaryIndex.setSelectionFromTop(mVisibleItem, 0);
```

So you can use `post()` method, just like below:

```
post(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
         mlvDictionaryIndex.setSelectionFromTop(mVisibleItem, 0);
     }
});
```